# htaccess redirect external url to relative path

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect http://www.example.com/api/request/ to a relative path like /handler/api/request/ so that I could proxy the API call:

but if I do this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /handler%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

result is this:

```
https://www.example.com/handle/api/request/
```

my expected result is

```
{my relative domain}/handler/api/request/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api(/.*)?$ handler%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Note there is no `R` flag and using relative path for rewrite.

Comment: This just adds handler to the source domain name
this is the output I get from the rule:
https://example.com/handler/api/observations-and-concerns
expected result should be:
/handler/api/observations-and-concerns
or 
relativedomain.com/handler/api/observations-and-concerns

Comment: This rule rewrites to a relative URL on current domain so `handler/api/observations-and-concerns` is relative path from current directory that contains `.htaccess`. Also don't understand what is `relativedomain.com`? If you rewrite to `relativedomain.com/handler%{REQUEST_URI}` then it will be a redirect not just rewrite.